# How to join to table with Sequelize without relations

Tags: sql, typescript, join, sequelize.js

I made an SQL command line to select what the data I want but I can't find a way to do it with Sequelize.

I have two tables. One with some id linked to names and the other one with long texts.
I want to select all the text containing names from the id of the name.

This SQL command is working :

```
SELECT 
    texts.id,
    texts.content
FROM
    text
    INNER JOIN users AS u ON u.id=38
WHERE
    LOWER(texts.content) like concat('%',u.name,'%')
```

When I try to do it with Sequelize, I have something like this :

```ts
this.modelTexts.findAll({
    include: [
        {
            model: this.modelUsers,
            where: { id: 38 },
        }
    ],
    where: ...
})
```

When I try this, I have this error message :

> SequelizeEagerLoadingError: users is not associated to texts!

I know I have to make something like :

```
Users.hasMany(Texts)
```

But I can't find a way to make it.

Thanks for taking a bit of your time for this request !

Comment: Please give a [mcve]. Also show what you tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Sequelize Raw](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/raw-queries.html) for this, so your query can be something like this

```
sequelize.query(`
  SELECT 
    texts.id,
    texts.content
  FROM
    text
  INNER JOIN users AS u ON u.id=38
    WHERE
  LOWER(texts.content) like concat('%',u.name,'%')`
{ type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT});
```

Or you can add associations. So wherever in your code you have define models, add the following code

```
User.hasMany('Text', {foreignKey: 'user_id'});
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer ! Actually that's what I did to "make it work" but as mentioned in another comment, you are not using Sequelize anymore when using raw request :/

Comment: You can add associations then, I have edited my answer.

Comment: The question is asking how to do it without associations. So the recommendation of creating the association is not a valid answer.

Answer (score 1):

### **NB: this solution was associated but if what you mean is no foreign keys on both tables**

To solve this, here is what i would do

I Added this to my association first

`models.User.hasMany(models.Text)`

then also added this in my find query

```
Text.findAll({ 
            attributes: ['id', 'content'],
            include: [
                {
                    model: users,
                    on: Sequelize.literal('users.id = 13')
                },
            ],
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

While the above answer is great, I think it may defeat the whole purpose of using sequelize. Have you tried the following:

- In your Text model definition:

  `Text.associate = models => {
     Text.belongsTo(models.User)
  }`
- In your User model definition:

  `User.associate = models => {
     User.hasMany(models.Text)
  }`

Let me know if you're still having trouble! Understanding how sequelize works will save you many many hours in the long run! :)

Comment: Hi Alan, thanks for your anwser. When I tried this, I got this error : "column text.user_id does not exist". I don't really know how to fix it :/

Comment: The question is asking how to do it without associations. So the recommendation of creating the association is not a valid answer.